# Create new network dataset in Arcgis Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am trying to create a new network dataset in ArcGIS Pro. I have created a feature dataset and imported the roads layer in it. After that i created topology and fixed the issues in road dataset. After that i am trying to create new road network by right clicking the feature dataset and there is no option to do this. 
i looked for tools in toolbox the only option i get is to create a network dataset from some template

Where i can get that template?

Why cannot i use my own schema?

Answer (score 2):

After verification with ESRI "officials", it appears that building a new network dataset without a template was not possible in the early version of ArcGIS Pro. It only becomes possible with version 2.5.

So, with ArcGIS Pro 2.5, use the geopressing tool "create network dataset". I didn't find the tool from the catalog view like in ArcGIS desktop. It only suggests "Feature class", "relationship class" and "topology"

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in ArcCatalog (make sure Network Dataset extension is enabled).
To create a new road network, right click on your feature dataset and choose "new>network dataset" 
You will be prompted to name it, then click next.  After you click next you should see all the layers available in your feature dataset.  Choose the road dataset you corrected.
The next several screens will ask you about the details of your network, like modeling turns, restrictions, elevation, if you want to establish driving directions, etc.  Set these as desired.  When you click finish you will be prompted to build the network.  And your road network will be built.  You should then be able to add your network to ArcMap and the corresponding layers will also be added. Use the Network Analyst in ArcMap to work with your network.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it is related to ArcGIS desktop, while the question is about ArcGIS Pro